# CSS3 Resize in Webkit/Safari

Tags: safari, webkit, css

I'm attempting to use CSS3's `resize` to make an absolutely positioned div resizable in Safari and Firefox Beta. No matter what I do I can't seem to make it work – are there situations that `resize` cannot be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for it to work in Safari, it seems to need `overflow:auto` applied to the div.

Additionally, the display `height` and `width` of the `div` will act as `min-height` and `min-width`.

This only worked for me in Safari, not in Firefox 3.5.

```
<div id="box"> Nice box </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
   /* important */
   resize: both;
   overflow: auto;

   /* Styling */
   background: red;
   position: absolute; /* per the question */
   top: 50px;
   left: 50px;
   width: 300px
}
```

Comment: I know have no memory of what I was trying to accomplish with this, but thanks for the help! Something "sticky notes" related I think…

Comment: This works well if the content is text. However, I want to use it for the "map" object (div) of OpenLayers. When the OSM map is drawn inside the div, the thumb at the right/bottom corner is covered by the map and I cannot drag it with the mouse anymore and I cannot resize the element. Is there a solution for that?