# React: Resizing a div including handlers, different cursors i.e ns-resize - no jquery

Tags: javascript, css, dom, reactjs

I am looking for an easy way of allow a user to resize a div using handles and all relevant cursors. I see lots of examples using jquery but I would like to use it in react and jquery isn't required.

Does anyone know a easy way of doing this ? I presume pure js, css. I don't really want to use a react component for this, as I need to enable resizing on standard divs.

Of course it is for use with reactjs, is there a more modern way of doing this without jquery ?

** EDIT **

These are the cursors that could be used for each resizable point

> e-resize     ne-resize n-resize     nw-resize s-resize     se-resize
>   w-resize     sw-resize

Answer (score 22):

You can only with CSS, `resize` property allows you to make that!

```css
.resize {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  overflow:auto;
}
.resize.horizontal {
  resize: horizontal;
}
.resize.vertical {
  resize: vertical;
}
.resize.both {
  resize: both;
}
.wrap {
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="resize horizontal">Resize me!</div>
  <div class="resize vertical">Resize me!</div>
  <div class="resize both">Resize me!</div>
</div>
```

### Requirements

`overflow` different than `visible` (initial) is required and you can apply it to all elements whos overflow is setted with `auto`, `scroll` and `hidden`.

I call this property marvellous!

Comment: Nice version with CSS, but doesn't allow to resize from each corner, only lower right

Comment: Yeah @Martin. The resize from another corner makes you doing calculations , not only sum and substract pixels, because when you resize from top left corner you are making wide the box and you are modifying the top left position of the box. That's not trivial and needs several lines of javascript to allow resize from all corners.

Comment: In many browsers (including Chrome/webkit) you can only resize to expand the element's area; you cannot make the element smaller as with other solutions. You can actually see the difference by checking out the "add a comment" textarea here (I'm using it now), and the "Your Answer" rich text editor below, which can be resized to be smaller (along the y-axis), not just enlarged.

Comment: Not supported by IE.

Comment: For safari look at this also - then worked fine for me (with overflow hidden or auto): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1838028/334402

Answer (score 7):

Heres an example of a great solution using **react-resize-panel** library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resize-panel

Put anything you want to show inside the *divs*, you can customize the handler too.

```
import ResizePanel from "react-resize-panel";

...

<div style={{
  width: '80%',
  height: '500px',
  border: '1px solid black',
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column'}}>
  <ResizePanel direction='s' style={{backgroundColor: 'black', height: '50%'}}>
    <div style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', height: '100%'}}>panel</div>
  </ResizePanel>
  <div style={{backgroundColor: 'purple', flexGrow: '1'}}>panel</div>
</div>

...
```

Hope this can help someone else

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I wanted to build something like this but with 2 `div elements`.
using `resize` property from css made it's width 0 when there are multiple elements so I tried javascript.

I saw an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-resizable-sidebar-forked-pd01lc) using `onMouseMove` event but there are many problems with this example so I made a new [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/resizeable-divs-tailwindcss-ubvmi6) in which I use the **`onDrag`** event.

Here is the important code:

```
const dragHandler = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      const w =
        ((e.clientX -
          e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
            .left) /
          e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
            .width) *
        100;
      if (w > 0 && w !== width) {
        setWidth(w);
      }
    },
    [width]
  );
```

and

```
<Box width={width} />
  <div
    draggable
    onDrag={dragHandler}
    className="flex justify-center items-center p-1 h-full bg-slate-800 cursor-col-resize"
  >
    <div className="w-1 border-x border-white h-1/6" />
  </div>
<Box width={100 - width} />
```

Hope it helps \(^_^)/

Comment: I could not find the original example but I forked it on codesandbox so I probided the link to that.